# How to sample data from table object in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Am trying to create a procedure where I can pass the `sampling` parameter, I tried many methods and failed...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc_sampling (
    v_sample     NUMBER
) AS

BEGIN

    -- USE SAMPLE PARAMETER (v_sample) TO SAMPLE THE BELOW SUB-QUERY
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
           *
        FROM
            t1,
            t2,
            t3
        WHERE
            t1.id=t2.id
            and t2.fid=t3.fid

    ) LOOP



        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO mytable (
               x,y,z
            ) VALUES (
               v1,v2,v3
            );

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                NULL;
        END;

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: What is your desired output from this procedure. Please be specific to your requirement only as there might be some easy solution available.

Comment: I just need to pass a value to be used as a `sampling` parameter inside a procedure, I will explain more

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE ( rs ) where rownum<=20` Try this!!

Comment: @Tejash actaully I wanted to use sample, as it would change the result to be better represetative to my case

Comment: Your update seems like a completely different problem from the first one you posted. But your requirement is still unclear. I think you want to restrict the number of rows inserted into `mytable` using the `v_sample` parameter. Do you have any further criteria (for example, randomness)?

Comment: The edit removed the `table` function - are you using this or not?

Comment: I tried different methods ... but the current question is the core and current logic

Comment: @APC randomness is a goal, yes

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__GUID-49792FA3-A1CC-4497-874A-631543D425A4):

> You can specify the SAMPLE clause in a query on a base table, a
>   container table of a materialized view, or a view that is key
>   preserving. You cannot specify this clause on a view that is not key
>   preserving.

So a table function is neither a base table, container table of a materialized view, or key preserved view.

To return some random rows, you could `order by dbms_random.value` then get the first N rows:

```
select *
from   table (
  cast (
    multiset (
      select level
      from dual 
      connect by level <= 10
    ) as sys.odcivarchar2list
  )
)
order  by dbms_random.value
fetch first 3 rows only;

COLUMN_VALUE   
6               
2               
10
```

Note this will have to sort the whole data set. If this is large it might take a while!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code which uses `DBMS_RANDOM` package in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_SAMPLING (
    V_SAMPLE NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    -- USE SAMPLE PARAMETER (v_sample) TO SAMPLE THE BELOW SUB-QUERY
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MYTABLE (X, Y, Z)
            SELECT
                <your_related_cols>
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        <your_related_cols>,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()) AS RN
                    FROM
                        T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                        JOIN T3 ON T2.FID = T3.FID
                )
            WHERE RN <= 20;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
    END;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```